# How to store GPS coordinates in FlashBuilder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm developing an application, and I need to store all of the GPS coordinates in a database. I could store it but only the last coordinates.

My question is, how can I store all the coordinates of a user's activity? I'm using a WAMP server. This is my code, which stores only the last coordinates. Note I'm storing only Long and Lat with this code

```
protected function onUpdate(event:GeolocationEvent):void {
  trace("Update event called");
  log.text = "latitude = " + event.latitude +
    "\nlongitude = " + event.longitude +
    "\naltitude = " + event.altitude +
    "\nverticalAccuracy = " + event.verticalAccuracy +
    "\nhorizontalAccuracy = " + event.horizontalAccuracy +
    "\nspeed = " + event.speed +
    "\nheading = " + event.heading +
    "\ntimestamp = " + event.timestamp;
  lat.text="" + event.latitude;
  long.text="" + event.longitude;
  langTextInput.text = long.text
  latTextInput.text=lat.text
  gpstableService.commit();
```

Comment: Do you really need to store it in the database? What about a sharedObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first question you need to ask yourself is whether you want to store this coordinates locally or on your WAMP server.

If you only need them locally, then an easy option is to use a local SharedObject (you can for example store any new position with the date you receive your event as the key).
If you really want to use a local database, then you could use a service like this one:

```
package
{
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
    import flash.data.SQLStatement;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.SQLEvent;

    public class DatabaseService extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public var conn:SQLConnection;

        public function DatabaseService()
        {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, handleConnectionSuccess);
            conn.openAsync(null);
        }

        public function addCoordinates(lat:String, long:String):void
        {
            var insertStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            insertStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "INSERT INTO coordinates (latitude, longitude)" +
                " VALUES (" + lat + ", " + long + ")";
            insertStmt.text = sql;
            insertStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, handleInsertionResult);
            insertStmt.execute();
        }

        private function createTable():void
        {
            var createStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            createStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinates " +
                "( coordId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude TEXT, longitude TEXT)";
            createStmt.text = sql;
            createStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, handleTableCreationResult);
            createStmt.execute();
        }

        private function handleConnectionSuccess(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            createTable();
        }

        private function handleTableCreationResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }

        private function handleInsertionResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var stmt:SQLStatement = event.target as SQLStatement;
            stmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, handleInsertionResult);
            trace ("Coordinates are saved in DB");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call this service every time you receive a GPS event:

```
    protected function onUpdate(event:GeolocationEvent):void
    {
        trace("Update event called");
        gpsTableService.addCoordinates(event.latitude, event.longitude);
    }
```

Where `gpsTableService` is an instance of `DatabaseService`.

In case you need to send this information on your server, then your should write a PHP script to handle your request. This script will be responsible for the database management, i.e. to store the data into it. To call this script from your Flash application, you'll then need to make user a `URLVariable`, a `URLRequest` and a `URLLoader`.